# How to configure security groups to connect Laravel Vapor to AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-security-group, laravel-vapor

I have an AWS RDS that is correctly set up to allow inbound traffic on port 3306 from an ELB that load balances two EC2 instances. This is all working as it should, and has been for some time.

I'm now deploying a new application to a Laravel Vapor environment, which also needs to connect to the same RDS. The application is deployed and accessible in a browser - but as soon as the DB comes into play (login), it times out and throws a Gateway error.

My Vapor environment is configured to use the same subnets as the RDS, and belongs to the same VPC. I have confirmed this in the AWS console.

I created a new security group specifically for the Vapor resources, and this is also specified in the vapor.yml. I can also confirm that this is attached to the Vapor lambdas as expected.

I have added an inbound rule to the security group attached to the RDS to allow ALL traffic from the Vapor security group. I have variously experimented with opening port 3306 only, but eventually broadened to ALL incoming traffic from that SG.

I continue to see exactly the same issue - timeout when making a DB request.

I still believe this to be a network security issue - if the DB credentials were wrong then I wouldn't expect a timeout, I would expect an application error of some kind. Can anybody see anything I've missed here, or point me to the logs that I'd need to look at to work out what's wrong with my setup?

Comment: "I have an AWS RDS that is correctly set up to allow inbound traffic on port 3306 from an ELB that load balances two EC2 instances." Traffic between the server and the database does not involve the load balancer (ELB) at all. So your description should not work unless you also have the same security group assigned to the EC2 servers that you have assigned to the load balancer.

Comment: There is an inbound rule on the RDS security group that allows port 3306 traffic from the security group that was created with the Elastic Beanstalk setup (described as 'SecurityGroup for ElasticBeanstalk environment.'). So perhaps not to the load balancer itself, but certainly allows traffic from the EC2's behind the load balancer in.

Comment: Is the RDS database configured to be public? In other words, is the "publicly accessible" setting on the RDS instance enabled?

Comment: yes, it's public

Comment: I think the Lambda function is resolving the database at its public IP address, and trying to go over the Internet to make the connection. I suggest making the database private.

Comment: making the rds private didn't change anything, same timeout issue at the same point.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use security groups in pairs, or chain them if you have more than a couple tiers in your architecture.  So for your scenario:

Pairs: (you need one extra group for the public)

- Public: open 80/443 to 0.0.0.0/0 - this goes on the load balancer
- WebClient: empty group - this goes on the load balancer
- WebServer: open 80 or 443 to WebClient group - this goes on the autoscaling group / EC2 instances, depending on if you're using http or https for load balancer -> instance communication
- DBClient: empty group - this goes on the autoscaling group / EC2 instances
- DBServer: open 3306 to the DBClient group - this goes on RDS

Chaining:

- Public: open 80/443 to 0.0.0.0/0 - this goes on the load balancer
- Web: open 80 or 443 to Public group - this goes on the autoscaling group / EC2 instances
- DB: open 3306 to Web group - this goes on the RDS instance

Comment: I am tryng to add my custom vpc to vapor. I am reading your post but I am not able to make it works. Any help? Thanks.